# CSS Grid layout with double width first item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a Grid-based layout where items will be laid out in a flexible grid, achieved using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr))`. Items then get auto-placed into the grid, which works well.

I'd like the first item to be double-width, so it spans two columns. This is pretty easy to achieve using a rule like this:

```css
.grid > *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}
```

However, this causes a problem once there's not enough space to fit two columns in – a second small column still appears, smaller than our minimum of 400px, and this ruins the nice regular grid on the second row onwards. My understanding is that the `span 2` essentially forces the algorithm to create an extra column. Is there any option short of using JS to measure the grid container and add and remove the `span 2` when there's not enough room? This grid will be used on multiple pages at different widths, so I can't just use a media query to enable/disable this behaviour.

Here's the code to reproduce the problem:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-columns: none;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}

.item {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > *:first-child {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  grid-column: 1/span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div> 
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/alxcr/full/JjyBXNW) for a live example of the problem (resize the viewport to around 700px to see it).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to move the column rule into a media query. You'd need to account for the margin/padding on the document and any ancestors - on my computer, that seems to be `8px`, so a `min-width: 816px` query works.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 8px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.item {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>*:first-child {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

@media (min-width: 816px) {
  .grid>*:first-child {
    grid-column: 1/span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/gjtosh79/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the media query approach isn't one I can use easily for this, since this code will appear on multiple pages with various other things to the left and right of it, so there's no fixed viewport width value I could use for a breakpoint.

Comment: Sounds like the sort of problem that [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) would solve, if any browser had actually implemented them. :)